# Matching words with a pipe in the middle

Tags: .net, regex

I'm starting to try to learn regex, and I want to try to figure out a regex that will find a match to an exact word, with a pipe character in the middle. For example:

I want it to find:

```
[[banana|banana]]
```

I want it to replace that with:

```
[[banana]]
```

If possible could there be a way to find quotes or something like that or with an "-s" or an "-ing"? For example:

Find:

```
EX 1: [[banana|"banana"]]
EX 2: [[apple|apples]]
EX 3: [[do|doing]]
```

Replaced with:

```
EX 1: [[banana]]
EX 2: [[apple]]s
EX 3: [[do]]ing
```

The question is, how would I do something like that? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen It's the regex for Wikipedia. I was editing Wikipedia and wanted to find and replace some things in articles. I believe they use .NET.

Comment: I tried this:    (\n[^\n]+)\1 which got me nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backreferences (`\1`) to match subexpression which has been already found:

```
\[\[([^]|]+)\|\"?\1(\w*)\"?\]\]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/e7LsGC/2

*Note: backslashes before double quotes are not necessary but without these SO syntax highlighter gets consused*

**Update**

Not sure what flavour Wikipedia uses but since .NET was mentioned in comments, [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5c%5b%28%5b%5e%5d%7c%5d%2b%29%5c%7c%22%3f%5c1%28%5cw*%29%22%3f%5c%5d%5c%5d&i=%5b%5bbanana%7cbanana%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bbanana%7c%22banana%22%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bapple%7capples%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bdo%7cdoing%5d%5d&r=%5b%5b%241%5d%5d%242) is a .NET demo. The regex is the same but substitution string changes to `[[$1]]$2`

**Update 2**

If optional word endings may comprise any characters and not only alphanumeric ones, the expression would be

```
\[\[([^]|]+)\|("?)\1([^]]*)\2\]\]
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5c%5b%28%5b%5e%5d%7c%5d%2b%29%5c%7c%28%22%3f%29%5c1%28%5b%5e%5d%5d*%29%5c2%5c%5d%5c%5d&i=%5b%5bbanana%7cbanana%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bbanana%7c%22banana%22%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bapple%7capples%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bdo%7cdoing%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bbanana%7cbanana%40%5e%40%40%23%24%40%23%24na%5d%5d&r=%5b%5b%241%5d%5d%243)

Please note in this case the second match group is used internally in the regex so the substitution string should be changed to `[[$1]]$3`.

Comment: But are we sure that Wikipedia edit supports backreferences?

Comment: 1+ . Try to provide regex in the language he uses.

Comment: What about that ? [[banana|banana@^@@#$@#$na]]

Comment: The software that I'm using has 2 boxes. One for find, and one for replace. What would I put in each one?

Comment: @Yoshi24517: the regex `\[\[([^]|]+)\|\"?\1(\w*)\"?\]\]` in the find box and substitution string `[[$1]]$2` (or `[[\1]]\2` depending on regex flavour) in the replacement one

Comment: It seems the flavour is .NET. It worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman: the OP implicitly suggests word endings would be alphabetic, but if any characters may take place, [`\[\[([^]|]+)\|"?\1([^]]*)"?\]\]` would do the trick](https://regex101.com/r/e7LsGC/3)

Comment: @DmitryEgorov your link in comment yields [[banana]]" where the quote is invalid

Comment: The actual regex in the answer worked. It got rid of the quote.

Comment: But if it contains anything like [[banana|"banana&@#!"]] then it will fail where the output should be like [[banana]]&@#!

Comment: As far as I've seen, where I have been fixing them manually, nobody uses @#$^%$#.

Comment: To see a Wikipedia edit with the regex in action, see this edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=15_cm_SK_L/45&diff=prev&oldid=770569561 Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
\[\[([^|]+)\|"?\1([^\]\["]*)"?\]\]
```

And Replace By:

`\[\[\1\]\]\2  or \[\[$1\]\]$2` (use dollar or slash depending on your software or lang )

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HKx2nb/2)

Reason Behind posting this solution is:

\w* will only cover a-zA-Z0-9_ so even if the text doesn't contain anything like &*&#$ still it may fail for single quotes for example:

[[does|doesn't]]

So to cover the above example you need this solution